# Locations outside of a Card for Plugin?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We are currently in the process of implementing a chat widget for our customers that use Banno.

Are there any locations outside of a card on the dashboard, where our chat can be initiated within your UI? In our experience with clients, to provide the best customer service, we persist a chat icon across all pages given that customer service can be needed anywhere on their side.

What user experiences and chat launch points have been done with other chat vendors that have integrated with Banno?

Our preferred UI approach:
Chat icon in lower right that opens an iframe or pops to a chat experience in another browser window.  We have found this to be the most common chat experience in the digital banking marketplace.

Went through https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

The short answer is that plugins can't modify the Banno UI beyond the card's boundary.

There are alternatives to plugins which use the same Authentication Framework: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/getting-started/#alternatives-to-plugins

- ...but notable they also have their own restrictions and don't allow for modifying the Banno UI beyond the ways described in the docs.

### Longer answer

From the [Restrictions page in the Plugin Framework docs](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/):

> Plugins cannot modify any part of Banno’s UI beyond the designated area of their Dashboard card.

The same is true of other [External application link types](https://knowledge.banno.com/apps/partnerintegrations/linktypes/).

In our experience chat vendors have usually built a plugin card for a quick summary view of the experience, and used either a primary action button or the Plugin Bridge to [activate the Expanded View](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/#activating-the-expanded-view-from-the-card-face) into their full chat experience.

Comment: Thank you Jaime. I don’t see Chat in the External Application Links so it looks like we will need to do a card plugin with either Action Button or a Plugin Bridge with a chat icon.

Will both of these approaches work with the Mobile App?

Comment: Yes, plugins are expected to be responsive and adapt to the UX in both Banno Online and Banno Mobile. We recommend checking out this page on the UI differences: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/